# compare columns of groups dataframe for equality

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My goal her is to compare a string or numeric among a group grouped by ID. So if for example var1 both were "NORMAL" a new column would say TRUE or FALSE. I know I can `summarise_all()` but I need it to be new column for another project. Also I would like this comparison to work for a numeric as well. All have to be exactly the same in the column of choice. Some of the groups have more than 2 members.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A1.1234567", "A1.12345"), 
                 var1 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var2 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var3 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var4 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var5 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var6 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var7 = c("25", "25"), 
                 var8 = c("6, 9)),

            .Names = c("ID", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I want it to look like

```
         ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6 var7 var8 var7.true va8.true
A1.1234567 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL  25    6    TRUE   FALSE
A1.1234567 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL  25    9    TRUE   FALSE
```

My only idea was to mutate it but I cant seem to compare them correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at`(as opposed to `mutate_all`) in order to not include `ID` since we are not grouping by it, and define the name of the new variables to be created so that it does not overwrite the existing ones, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-ID), funs(new = ifelse(all(. == 'NORMAL'), TRUE, FALSE)))
```

which gives

> ```
>              ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8 var1_new var2_new var3_new var4_new var5_new var6_new var7_new var8_new
> 1 A1.1234567_10 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
> 2 A1.1234567_20 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
> ```

**EDIT** As per your comment, there are a few ways to get equality in all elements. I went with the length of the unique value being 1 (If all are the same), i.e.

```
mutate_at(df, vars(-ID), funs(new = length(unique(.)) == 1))
```

*BONUS* Now you don't need to use `ifelse` since we are not defining a value

Comment: this works really well for some of my columns were there are set number of options. However, how can I use this more in a way that checks equivalence if it were numeric, with a large range. If I'm not clear let me know

Comment: I m not sure I understand. Can you edit your example in the question to include such a case?

Comment: I changed it to reflect numeric as well as character

Comment: @Randy I edited my answer. Please have a look and let me know